# How can I duplicate mouse and keyboard USB HID input across multiple computers?

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, game-controller

How can I send the same USB HID input to 2-4 Windows PCs from a single mouse and keyboard? I.e. mouse movement on one system causes identical mouse movement on the other connected system(s).

I think I need a hardware solution, or software that will capture and input before [Xinput/DirectInput](http://zeppelinstudio.net/directinput-vs-xinput/) to be compatible.

Comment: You didn't know, but since this needs a hardware solution, this question sorta kinda fits better in https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

[USB-844-KM-BC 4 port USB Keyboard & Mouse Multiplier / Multicaster](http://supermicro.com/products/system/1U/1029/SYS-1029GP-TR.cfm) is a hardware USB HID multiplier that duplicates HID input to multiple PCs simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

[Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) is a commercial product is designed to allow one keyboard and one mouse to control multiple PCs (MacOS, Windows, & Linux).  Alternatives include:

[Debauchee/Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier), open source, multiple OS, but you must compile it
[Input Directory](http://www.inputdirector.com/), free for noncommercial use, Windows only
[Mouse Without Borders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460&ranMID=43674&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-APbtfn6fjgfMvivgcqfNEw&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-APbtfn6fjgfMvivgcqfNEw&irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7795_1243925&tduid=(ir__c0brgmzpkqqtwlpfgjf9dgvoqu2xhwkfbr0znlpk00)(7795)(1243925)(je6NUbpObpQ-APbtfn6fjgfMvivgcqfNEw)()&irclickid=_c0brgmzpkqqtwlpfgjf9dgvoqu2xhwkfbr0znlpk00), Windows only, free for now
[Multiplicity](https://www.stardock.com/products/multiplicity/), Windows only, commercial product
[win2vnc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win2vnc/), open source, Windows only
[x2vnc](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/x2vnc.html), 2 PCs only, Windows & Linux, open source

Comment: These are all software KVM solutions that won't achieve the desired behavior. Will add clarification to the question.

Input Director comes closest, but duplicating the mouse with Input Director doesn't work with Xinput/DirectInput on the non-source systems. The cursor doesn't move.